Gaposa Rollapp not connecting to shade that's already synced to a remote
I have a 16 channel remote that moves my shades up, down, and to a stop. I can get the remote to "sync" to the shade by holding down the button above "A". When I do that, the RollUp app appears to catch that "sync" (and I push the appropriate up or down button on the app), but the app never works after hitting submit.
How can I get the RollUp Android app to record the blind movements from the existing working RF remote?

Added clear ask at the end

It appears that this app requires additional hardware: RollApp hub
See https://www.gaposa.it/eng/news/rollapp/  and https://www.avoutlet.com/window-treatments/shade-components/remote-controls/gaposa-rollapp/  Do you have this hardware (hub) ?
